# build with google/draco as lib by pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

My test project look:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── draco
├── pybind11
├── setup.py
└── src
    |-main.cpp
```

I am writing python wrapper for draco with `pybind11`
Because I am new to C++, I don't know how to build draco as share lib
There is my simple `CMake.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)
project(test)

add_subdirectory(draco)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(test src/main.cpp )
```

In `main.cpp`, I just new a `draco::Mesh` pointer

I build my test project. Import it in Python get the error

```
test.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5draco4MeshC1Ev
```

The error may be mean that I don't link the draco lib to `test` target

why the problem happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `target_link_libraries` command in CMakeLists.txt.